# How to prove $p ∧ (q ∧ r) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∧ r)$

Tags: proof-verification

As the title says, how to prove $p ∧ (q ∧ r) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∧ r)$ without using conjunctional laws?

I did attempt this question on my own, but found myself running into road blocks.

Comment: well with all the same operator, parenthesis can be removed and since it is commutative you are just left with $p\land p=p$ simplification.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the truth table?

Comment: What are "conjunction laws".  But this seems trivial If $p \land (q\land r)$ then $p$.  And also $q\land r$ so $q$.  So $p\land q$.  And because of $q\land r$ we have $r$ so with $p$ with have $p\land r$.  So we have both $p\land q$ and $p\land r$ so $(p\land q)\land(p\land r)$.  So $p\land(q\land r)\implies(p\land q)\land(p\land r)$. And if we have $(p\land q)\land(p\land r)$ we have $p\land q$ so $p$ and we have $p\land q$ so $q$ and $p\land r$ so $r$. So $q\land r$ and $p\land(q\land r)$.  So $(p\land q)\land(p\land r)\implies p\land(q\land r)$.

Comment: @zwim yes that would be simple. I should have mentioned, our professor is not allowing us to use commutative property.

Comment: Well if you cannot use any basic tools, I see no other solution than the truth table.

Comment: $p \wedge q \equiv p \wedge q \wedge p$

Comment: "Well if you cannot use any basic tools, I see no other solution than the truth table."  The OP doesn't say we can't use basic tools, just not commutative property and "conjunctive laws". I think the OP should tell us what tools we *can* use.

Comment: https://www3.risc.jku.at/education/courses/ws99/formal/slides/logic/index_19.html  Conjunctive laws seem to be commutivity and associativity.

Comment: @OP so what rules *can* you use?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what conjunctional laws are, but you can check they are the same all eight cases:

______p______q______r______p&(q&r)______(p&q)&(p&r)____

______F______F______F______F_____________F__________

______F______F______T______F_____________F__________

______F______T______F______F_____________F__________

______F______T______T______F_____________F__________

______T______F______F______F_____________F__________

______T______F______T______F_____________F__________

______T______T______F______F_____________F__________

______T______T______T______T_____________T__________